How to insert an autoincremented variable when replacing content in file
My goal is to insert id=“#” near every found “match” string when parsing a file. Instead of # must be an incrementing number.
There are plenty of files that need to be parsed.
I’ve tried:
counter=0
find -type f -name "*.html" | xargs sed -i “s/match/id=$((++counter)) match/g”

But counter is always 1.
(In addition, it would be good to set counter to 0 at the beginning of the new file, but most important is just to make it incremented).
UPDATED: I understood that provided info was not enough. It might be hundreds of files, each of them - an html document. The line of one file may look like this:
<td><span>1.6.</span><span style="background-color:#FFC1C1">2</span>

The match I'm looking for is "background-color:#FFC1C1". There also might be hundreds of those matches per ONE file.
An expected result is:
<td><span>1.6.</span><span id=1 style="background-color:#FFC1C1">2</span>
/* more html here */
<td><span>Version</span><span id=2 style="background-color:#FFC1C1">4</span>
/* more html here */
<td><span>2.0.9</span><span id=3 style="background-color:#FFC1C1">2</span>
/* more html here */

But what I have now is:
<td><span>1.6.</span><span id=1 style="background-color:#FFC1C1">2</span>
/* more html here */
<td><span>Version</span><span id=1 style="background-color:#FFC1C1">4</span>
/* more html here */
<td><span>2.0.9</span><span id=1 style="background-color:#FFC1C1">2</span>
/* more html here */


please update the question with a couple sample input files (3-4 lines each, with and without matches) and the corresponding (expected) results; also, if a 'match' can occur more than once on a single line then insure you include this in the sample

please update the question with some metadata ... how many files are you talking about? how big (# of lines, MBytes) can these files get? how often do you need to run this operation (ie, is this a one-time operation or do you need to run this on an hourly, daily, weekly basis)? if you're talking about a large volume of changes (either in terms of number of changes or number of times this operation needs to be performed) then you'll likely want a solution that favors performance over brevity (of coding)

will it be possible that you run this process against a given file more than once and if so how should we proceed if we find a match was updated via a previous run? update the 'old' counter value with the newest/latest counter value? skip the match (ie, keep the 'old' counter value)? something else?

please update the question to include some realistic strings (patterns?) you'll actually be searching for; are you talking about (simple) alphanumeric strings? could 'match' include characters like /, *, ., etc? could 'match' be a regex?

This might work for you (GNU sed & shell):
sed -Ei '/style="background-color:#FFC1C1".*/!b
         s//id=\n &/
         x;s/.*/echo $((&+1))/e;x
         G;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' file1 file2 file3 filen

Set the extended regexp option -E and replace amended file inline option -i.
Unless a line contains style="background-color:#FFC1C1" we are not interested.
Prepend id=, a newline (as a marker for the counter) and a space before the style attribute.
Swap to the hold space and increment the current counter, then swap back to the pattern space.
Append the counter to the current line and using pattern matching insert the counter where the marker was already placed.
N.B. The -i ensures the counter will be reset for each file encountered.

In your command the expression $((++counter)) is only replaced once, when the command line is expanded. Use a loop so you can increment the variable each time.
counter=0
while read -r filename; do
    sed -i "s/match/id=$((++counter)) match/g" "$filename"
done < <(find -type f -name "*.html")

This code assumes there's only one match per file, or that all the IDs in each file should be the same counter.
And of course you can't re-run it on the same files, since it will add a second id= field to all the lines that were modified the first time.

It says here that you can use vim like this:
find . -type f -name '*.html' -exec vim -c ':argdo let n=[0] | %s/match/\="id=".map(n, "v:val+1")[0]." match"/g | w' -c q {} +

Don't run this command without taking backups.
